# "Could not but" in interrogative sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, could-modal

Is the following sentence grammatically correct to write in literature?

> How could I not but close my eyes?

As "I could not but close my eyes" is a valid sentence, I felt like this one should also be valid. But I am confused whether 'could not but' can be used like that in interrogative sentences.

Comment: Interestingly, the construction **could not but....** appears to have hit a peak of popularity in the 1820s - and has been declining ever since. So, yes it's grammatical but somewhat archaic. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=could+not+but%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccould%20not%20but%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I for one am having difficulty working out what it adds up to. If I met this in a book, I would be perplexed and have to work out what the writer meant: they had to close their eyes, or that they couldn't.

Comment: The cited usage is effectively "**emphatic repetition**". I can say either *How could I **not** laugh?* OR *How could I **but** laugh?* with exactly the same meaning *(I **had** to laugh)*. But to my ear today, the "double negation" of *How could I **not but** laugh?* sounds a bit weird, to say the least. It reminds me of *I **could / couldn't** care less*, where the meaning is the same regardless of how boolean logic and negation apply to the actual words used.

Answer (score 1):

Ronald is correct, this is archaic usage.

The difference between: "How could I not but close my eyes?"

and: "How could I not close my eyes?"

is that the first one is more like "How could I do anything else besides closing my eyes", it explicitly invokes rejecting the possibility of alternatives.  The second only mentions not doing something.

This is a very small distinction of meaning, and the first use (with 'but') will never be used by modern speakers.   You'll encounter it in some literature, however.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from this [Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=could%20not%20but%2Ccould%20but&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccould%20not%20but%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccould%20but%3B%2Cc0), both ***could not but*** and ***could but*** are possible, and although they were in decline in the last century, they seem to be currently picking up:

[image]

The idiomatic phrase is ***cannot but***, and yes, it is antiquated and more formal:

> You use ***cannot but, could not but,*** and ***cannot help but*** when you want to emphasize that you believe something must be true and that there is no possibility of anything else being the case.
>
> - [formal, emphasis]
> - e.g. She ***could not but*** congratulate him. ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cannot-but))

This example means that "***all she could do*** was to congratulate him".

As for ***can but*** it has a similar meaning:

> Can only.
>
> - I prepared for the exam, so now I ***can but do*** my best. ([Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/can+but))